# Issues encrypting root partition with Luks

Tags: luks, disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I was given a "golden image" of an out of date production server and was instructed to update and harden the OS for production delivery. The issue I am running into is that LUKS. I am using Suse 12.5.

When booting into an Ubuntu live CD to encrypt the root partition I get an error.

- There are 8 total partitions. The root (system) is on `sda3`.
- The command I am running is as follows:

  ```shell
  cryptsetup reencrypt /dev/sda3 --new --reduce-device-size 32m --type luks1
  ```
- The error that is returned is:

  ```
  WARNING: Device /dev/sda3 already contains a 'dos' partition signature.
  Device /dev/sda3 contains broken LUKS metadata. Aborting operation.
  ```
- Running `blkid /dev/sda3` returns

  ```
  LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID=too long to type BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE=ext4 PT type=dos partlable=primary partyuid=too long to type
  ```

I am using LUKS1 because I have read that GRUB only works with LUKS1 encryption.

Any help or another route would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I am still actively looking for a solution to encrypt an existing filesystem. If anyone has a different option I am willing to try that. My next idea is completely rebuilding the filesystem using a new hard drive, shuffling the data over. Will that sort of thing work? Still trying to get a good solution.

Comment: What is the filesystem type used on `sda3`? And did you shrink that filesystem by 32M before trying to run `cryptsetup reencrypt`? There is no universal filesystem shrinking tool embedded in `cryptsetup`: the `--reduce-device-size 32m` just means it's going to chop off the last 32M of the partition contents, so the filesystem had better not be using that part.

Comment: Grub since 2020 boots directly to lucs2. Before you had a separate /boot partition for grub to use to boot. GRUB Boot Loader Adds Support For LUKS2 Encrypted Disks
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GRUB-Boots-LUKS2-Disk-Encrypt Some other issues? https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Encrypted_root_file_system#Unattended_boot_with_TPM_2.0

Comment: Blkid /dev/sda3 reads: **LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID=too long to type BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE=ext4 PT type=dos partlable=primary partyuid=too long to type

Comment: Oldfred, Im worried that because I'm running on 12.5 I won't have an up to date enough grub to make this work.

Comment: Since you have long PARTUUIDs, your partition table is apparently GPT type. In that case, the partition type UUID for LUKS partitions should ideally be `CA7D7CCB-63ED-4C53-861C-1742536059CC` - but apparently `fdisk` does not know about that type UUID yet. However, `gdisk` seems to have it selectable with the short type code `8309`. I looked at the `cryptsetup` source code, but could not figure out why it would be complaining about `broken LUKS metadata` given that you are apparently trying to encrypt an existing unencrypted `ext4` partition. This might be a bug in `cryptsetup reencrypt --new`.

Comment: For some reason it detects 'dos' signature when it's supposed to look for 'crypto_LUKS' signatures exclusively. This could be intentional (partition table on partition table? shrinking that is annoying and reencrypt would break it...) or unintentional, the error message is confusing in any case, so report a bug... skimming over the code I'm not sure where this happens, could also be libblkid